# Parse a Date in Python with datetime

Tags: python, string, datetime, parsing

I am getting this String:

```
a = "Wed Mar 06 2019 17:35:33 GMT-0500 (Ecuador Time)"
```

and i am trying to parse it in python with this code:

```
fecha = datetime.strptime(a , '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)')
```

But i am getting an error

```
ValueError: time data 'Wed Mar 06 2019 17:35:33 GMT-0500 (Ecuador Time)' does not match format '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z (%Z)'
```

what am i doing wrong? i've try a lot of settings for the date but still can get a solution my goal is to get a date object  and save it into a MongoDatabase

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem with the code is "(Ecuador Time)" is not in the format required to match "(%Z)".

To fix your code, you can just simply remove "(Ecuador Time)" from your string and remove your "(%Z)". Since you already have your GMT offset, it shouldn't matter too much.

This would leave your code as:

```
from datetime import datetime

a = "Wed Mar 06 2019 17:35:33 GMT-0500"
fetcha = datetime.strptime(a , '%a %b %d %Y %H:%M:%S GMT%z')
```

Comment: Thank you so much this works i split the string this way:  `texto = a.split()`
`texto = texto[0]+" "+texto[1]+" "+texto[2]+" "+texto[3]+" "+texto[4]+" "+texto[5]`
and then i could parse it thank you again :)

Comment: I would recommend doing something like `a = "Wed Mar 06 2019 17:35:33 GMT-0500 (Ecuador Time)"` and then `a = a.split(' (')[0]` instead, but your way should work as well.